# Use 2 {{navigations}} in Ghost

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

This is my first time working with Ghost and creating my own theme. I noticed that in the admin panel, there are 2 areas for navigation: primary and secondary.
I would like to use the primary area to populate the links in the nav bar and the secondary in the footer. Both navbar and footer are their own partials.

Thank you for your time and assistance

The navigation.hbs is working correctly and I'm using:

```
{{#foreach navigation}}
                  <li class="nav-{{slug}}{{#if current}} nav-current{{/if}}"><a href="{{url absolute="true"}}">{{label}}</a></li>
{{/foreach}}
```

The footer.hbs is displaying "Coming soon!" and I'm using:

```
{{#if isSecondary}}
              <ul class="nav footer-nav" role="menu">
                {{#foreach navigation}}
                  <li class="nav-{{slug}}{{#if current}} nav-current{{/if}}"><a href="{{url absolute="true"}}">{{label}}</a></li>
                {{/foreach}}
             </ul>
{{else}}
             <p>Coming soon!</p>
{{/if}}
```

The default.hbs has:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{@site.locale}}"{{#match @custom.color_scheme "Dark"}} class="dark-mode"{{else match @custom.color_scheme "Auto"}} class="auto-color"{{/match}}>
<head></head>
<body class="{{body_class}} is-head-{{#match @custom.navigation_layout "Logo on cover"}}left-logo{{else match @custom.navigation_layout "Logo in the middle"}}middle-logo{{else}}stacked{{/match}}{{#match @custom.title_font "=" "Elegant serif"}} has-serif-title{{/match}}{{#match @custom.body_font "=" "Modern sans-serif"}} has-sans-body{{/match}}{{#if @custom.show_publication_cover}} has-cover{{/if}}">
<div class="viewport">

    {{navigation}}


    <div class="site-content">
        {{!-- All other templates get inserted here, index.hbs, post.hbs, etc --}}
        {{{body}}}
    </div>
    {{!-- {{log @site.secondary_navigation}} --}}
    {{!-- The global footer at the very bottom of the screen --}}  
    {{> footer}}


</div>

{{!-- Scripts - handle member signups, responsive videos, infinite scroll, floating headers, and galleries --}}
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="{{asset "built/tb-theme.js"}}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Mobile Menu Trigger
    $('.gh-burger').click(function () {
        $('body').toggleClass('gh-head-open');
    });
    // FitVids - Makes video embeds responsive
    {{!-- $(".gh-content").fitVids(); --}}
});
</script>

{{!-- Ghost outputs required functional scripts with this tag - it should always be the last thing before the closing body tag --}}
    {{!-- Below is a way to insert Ghost footer --}}
    {{ghost_foot}}

</body>
```

If I switch {{navigation}} to {{navigation type="secondary"}} then both navbar and footer will show the footer's links.

Answer (score 0):

WORKAROUND -> you can add a new website within your actual installation and use their default navigation.

I was looking for the same and that's the approach that I'm starting to work into.